# C++ thread performance

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, performance

I made a small program to observe the speed up of using two threads. I am timing a process of filling an array. A the main thread and thread1 call function_1 to inialize different halfs of the array. I was expecting to see faster results by using two thread. Instead, I got slower times and the commented-out code performs faster. Where am I going wrong with this?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


void function_1(int I, int J, int *B){
    for (int i = I; i<(J+1); i++) {
        B[i] = 100;
       //std::cout << B[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int *count;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    count = new int[20000];

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    //function_1(0, 19999, count);
    std::thread thread1(function_1, 0, 9999, count);
    thread1.join();
    function_1(10000, 19999, count);

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time_span = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << "time taken is :" <<time_span << " ms"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing your sample code synchronously by immediately joining thread1 right after you created it.  Execution in main() will block until that thread terminates processing and will then move to `function_1(10000, 19999, count);` In order to take advantage of the extra thread, try moving the join call after the call to `function_1(10000, 19999, count);` in main.

Comment: I moved the thread1.join() after the main's call to function_1. For some reason using two threads is still slower than using one thread with the commented-out code.

Comment: The test seems a bit too trivial. Thread management most likely affects your performance negatively. Threads aren't really a cost-free way to run things in parallel.

Comment: @Mario: That is really a small amount of work. You might try making the array 10 or 100 times larger.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks. After I made my array of 1 million, elements, I started to notice a difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::thread thread1(function_1, 0, 9999, count);
thread1.join();
function_1(10000, 19999, count);
```

The main thread will wait for `thread1` to finish working before calling `function_1`. This is the same as calling

```
function_1(...)
function_1(...)
```

on the main thread, only with the extra costs brought by managing threads. You might want to `join()` after you call `function_1` on the main thread.

Also, you should increase the workload to make testing more relevant. Threads aren't really a cost-free way to get work done fast. You need to consider the cost of maintaining threads before deciding whether or not they're relevant to your situation.

Comment: I moved the main thread's call to function_1 below the instantiation of thread1 and before thread1.join(). The timing is slightly improved from the original results. But for some reason, it is not faster than using one thread with the commented-out code.

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to see a major improvement when the task at hand consists only of filling memory.

The problem is fairly simple: a single core can probably saturate your full bandwidth to memory. That being the case, adding more threads can't do much good unless you have a computer with multiple processors, not just multiple cores in a single socket.

With multiple sockets you can get a speed improvement by having different threads running on separate physical processors, each with its own connection to memory. To make this effective, however, you typically need to use some non-standard function calls to ensure that each thread runs on a separate physical processor and ensure that the thread running on each processor writes to memory that's local to that processor.

Neither of those is exactly rocket science, but they're not necessarily trivial either. Even at the simplest, at least a little of the code is almost certain to be non-portable.

To see a major gain from multiple threads, you typically want to carry out tasks that include a mixture of various different types of work: e.g., some that's I/O bound, some that's memory bound, and some that's processor bound. In such a case, it's much easier to get a substantial speedup from multiple threads. If you can't have that, something that's heavily processor bound is probably the second choice. Assuming you can do so with little or not synchronization between threads, chances are pretty good that you can get a roughly linear speedup (i.e., N cores execute the code approximately N times faster than one core).